# Getstream Post activity 403

Tags: javascript, react-native, getstream-io

When trying to use **addactivity**() from **getstream** it returns a 403. The code I am using is here.

```
let client = stream.connect(apiKey, getTokenFromServer(),appId);
 let user = client.feed('user','x');
  let activity = {'actor': 'x', 'verb': 'tweet', 'object': 1, 'foreign_id': 'tweet:1'};
    user.addActivity(activity).then((data) =>{console.log('success')}).catch((reason) =>{alert(reason) });
```

Looking at the logs from getstream.io dashboard I see  'The request didn't have the right permissions or authorization. Please check our docs about how to sign requests.'

Currently using the token and the same exact user and feed I can post to a feed using the **react-native** components. This will work perfectly fine for the user and a snippet is below.

```
 <StreamApp
        apiKey=key
        appId=id
        token={token}>
        <FlatFeed Activity={this.CustomActivity} notify={true} feedGroup={this.props.feed} userId={this.props.userId} />
        <StatusUpdateForm  userId={x} feedGroup="user" />
      </StreamApp>
```

Answer (score 1):

The actor of your activity needs to be a user reference.
The correct activity is:

```
let activity = {'actor': client.user('x').ref(), 'verb': 'tweet', 'object': 1, 'foreign_id': 'tweet:1'}
```

Comment: Client.feed needs a token in order to be able to publish. Which is a different token from user token.  This can be obtained using an api endpoint using the method createReadWriteToken(slug, id) and then you'll be able to post an activity

Comment: does the documentation cover this anywhere?